# react-native: Catch screen lock

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mobile-application

[AppState](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate.html) exposes an `inactive` state but there is no way to determine if the user locked the screen or minimized the app. Is there a way to capture the locking of the screen?

Comment: have you find the answer?!